# Is it possible to mark doctests in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7

I'd like to mark my doctests as unit tests (with a custom marker) so `pytest -m unit` runs all unit tests including doctests (without needing to specify `--doctest-modules`), but marking the enclosing function doesn't seem to do this, and nor does marking the entire module as containing unit tests. Is there a way to apply markers to doctests so they can be discovered and ran with `pytest -m <marker>`, and not run if the marker is not provided?

Answer (score 0):

Appears not to be implemented at the moment. See this ongoing discussion https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5794
Have a look [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/doctest.html?highlight=getfixture#alternatives). Maybe pytest-plus or sybil provide you what you need.